# How to add `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` to the classpath variable in windows?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

My classpath is linked to junit home which contains both `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and `junit-4.12.jar`. The junit seems to be recognized but I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing`.

I think I have to link the hamcrest to the classpath variable somehow but I'm not sure how.

This is my classpath variable's contents:

`%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;.;`

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the CLASSPATH variable?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Java 8 Classpath specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) you could change your classpath entry to:

`%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%/*;.;`

Specifically:

> Class path entries can contain the base name wildcard character (*), which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all of the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry mydir/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named mydir. A class path entry consisting of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory. Files are considered regardless of whether they are hidden (have names beginning with '.').